# How to animate something at the same time in GASP?

Tags: animation, gsap

I want to animate these two things at the same time, and not one by one.

```js
t1.fromTo(searchForm, { scaleX: 0 }, { duration: 1, autoAlpha: 1, scaleX: 1 });
t1.fromTo(loupe, {x: '-=0'}, {duration: 1, x: '+=265'})
```

I want to move them together; how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the position parameter to position your tween(s) wherever you want in the timeline.

```
t1.fromTo(searchForm, { scaleX: 0 }, { duration: 1, autoAlpha: 1, scaleX: 1 });
t1.fromTo(loupe, {x: '-=0'}, {duration: 1, x: '+=265'}, 0);
```

There's more info about the position parameter at https://greensock.com/position-parameter.

Also, there's no reason to use a `.fromTo()` in the second case because `x: "-=0"` does absolutely nothing, so you can just to a normal `.to()` tween and omit that whole object.

Happy tweening!

Comment: For more tips on animating efficiently see [this post](https://css-tricks.com/tips-for-writing-animation-code-efficiently/).